# bibtex file does not recognize the citations

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to compile "bibtex filename.aux" in latex. It does not compile and the errors are:

1. Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
2. File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK \begin{document}
3. File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK \begin{document}

The main problem is the first error.
The command line with the problem in the filename.aux says:
\providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers (So apparently this is the line with a problem)

Here are the lines in the .tex file

\usepackage{natbib}

text... \citep{author2002}...etc

I have no idea how to make it run. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Can you prepare a minimal example [MWE](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) that lets us reproduce the problem? Right now there isn't enough information. FYI: [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is a modern alternative and could be of interest for you.

Comment: Which bibliography style file are you using? Did you try loading `natbib` with the option `authoryear`?

Comment: In my case I was using TexStudio 2.9.4 and I resolved this same issue by looking carefully in Tools -> Bibliography, a log file about the bibliography compilation, and I resolved every issue it has warned me, like missing commas.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us which bibliography style you use, but it would appear to be one that generates a *numeric* citation style by default.

If the bibliography style is not completely incompatible with authoryear-style citations (a big if, given the first error message you report...), you could try issuing the command

```
\setcitestyle{authoryear}
```

after loading `natbib` so that `\citet` and `\citep` can create citations in the desired authoryear style. After adding the command given above, be sure to wipe out the .aux file and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX (twice more) .

If your bibliography style does turn out to be incompatible with authoryear-style citations, you either need to find another, compatible style file or create your own custom .bst style file from scratch. Fortunately, the latter method isn't as difficult as it might seem, thanks to the existence of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package (which was created, incidentally, by the author of the `natbib` package).